# How can I set read only access to ssh git server?

Tags: git, ssh, repository, shared, git-clone

I have a git repo on my server that I can push/pull through SSH just fine like:

```
git clone ssh://user@domain.com/repositories/myrepo.git
```

It prompts me with my public key passcode and I'm able to fetch or push changes to it, but I was wondering if there was a way where I could set it up so people can `clone` it only with read access so they don't have to enter any SSH credentials.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not through ssh; unless you wanted to distribute a public is they could log in with, and that is a terrible idea.

The way we got this functionality on our gitolite was to use git-daemon; you need to open a new port, but can specify per-repository which ones it will serve, and can specify read-only. Users would clone with the git protocol i.e.

> git clone git://domain.com/repositories/myrepo.git

Another way is to set the repository to be shared over a web server directly; then the user could access over standard http.

The page on the git community book [here](http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html) is a good overview, along with the man pages for `git-daemon`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up moving it to my public_html folder so I could use standard http, I was getting some problems trying to set up git-daemon maybe because of my shared hosting.

Comment: I hope this necropost is okay. I have two (dumb?) questions. 1) If a person wanted the encryption offered by the ssh protocol, doesn't this answer remove that advantage, because the git protocol doesn't encrypt? 2) Why is it a terrible idea to distribute a public key to whomever needs read-only access? Is it not possible to prevent shell access and anything else that the RO user shouldn't have? I ask because I'm looking for a solution, myself.

Comment: 1) Yes, it would remove the SSH protocol safety. I don't think git:// access is really a good solution in 2022!
2) The literal interpretation of the original question would imply giving ssh shell access - which is almost certainly a bad idea. It's possible to restrict shell access, manually - but - probably a good idea to leave this job to something like gitolite (if still recommended - I haven't kept up with current best practice for this style of personal access) or GitLab, rather than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`git-daemon`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).  That will remove the dependency on having valid ssh credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git-shell, set only read permissions on the repository, and use key authentication. This is feasible when you are in control of who gets the key.

Answer (score 1):

Given that:

- `git clone ssh://remote/src/proj1` and subsequent `git pull` / `git fetch` execute `git-upload-pack 'src/proj1'` (with the quotes)
- `git push` etc executes `git-receive-pack 'src/proj1'` on the remote server

in your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` you can setup a line beginning with:

```
command="/home/yourusername/bin/checker" ssh-…
```

where the … part is the public key of the private SSH key you will give your users.

The `/home/yourusername/bin/checker` can be a shell script along the lines:

```
case $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in
(git-upload-pack*)
     # run git-upload-pack after unquoting its argument, optionally further restricting
     # access to specific directories
     ;;
(git-receive-pack*)
     exit 1 # deny access
     ;;
(*)
     exit 1 # allow nothing else
     ;;
esac
```

Please check the [authorized_keys man page](http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys) for extra security options like `no-port-forwarding` which most probably you want to include along the `command="…"` option in your `authorized_keys` file.