# How to set up an ssh key for read-only git access

Tags: git, ssh, repository, git-pull, git-clone

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620584/how-can-i-set-read-only-access-to-ssh-git-server), and the accepted answer rejects setting up what I want.

My company has set up a git server.  I have a private ssh key on my personal computer from which I can access that server, read from git, and write changes to git.

I also need read access to git from a server where other people have root access.  I'm not willing to put my private git ssh key with read-write access on a server where other people can read it.  As a consequence, I end up having to connect with https, and type in my user name and password every time I want to download from git.  This is sub-optimal.

Is there a way that I can add a key to git that has my credentials, but only read access?  If not, can I at least set up git on my server account so that it knows my user name, and I only have to type in my password?

Comment: The linked question has 2 other answers — setup `git-shell` or `git-daemon` at the server-side. In addition to this I can add `gitolite`.

Comment: @phd It's a corporate server.  I have 0 control over it

Comment: Then the question should be forwarded to you corporate overlords. Because the accepted answer is still true: not through ssh.